# Why would individual reducers work, but implementing combine reducer throw errors?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to implement a combine reducer, if someone could lend an eye, everything I see is right.  If I put each individual reducer in it works, but then put in rootReducer and nothing works. Giving me error of props.mutts/felines/applicants.map is not a function.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import  applicantReducer  from './reducers/applicantReducer';
import  catReducer  from './reducers/catReducer';
import  dogReducer  from './reducers/dogReducer';
import App from './App';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
       applicants: applicantReducer, 
       cats: catReducer,
       dogs: dogReducer
})

let store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function **map** can only be used for arrays, not for objects.

If you console.log() **props.mutts** , you'll see that it's an OBJECT.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the reducer in my mapStateToProps, in the container files.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        cats: state.catReducer.cats
    }
}
```